# Jquery load text into div - multiple values/divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, text, load

I have a text file with multiple lines that I need loaded into different divs.   Text file looks like:

```
Jon
Doe
25

Jane
Doe
37

Foo
Bar
18
```

How can I load this file and populate the following divs?

```
<input id="firstname" type="text"></input>
<input id="lastname" type="text"></input>
<input id="age" type="text"></input>

<input id="firstname1" type="text"></input>
<input id="lastname1" type="text"></input>
<input id="age1" type="text"></input>

<input id="firstname2" type="text"></input>
<input id="lastname2" type="text"></input>
<input id="age2" type="text"></input>
```

Loading the div with

```
   $(".myDiv").load("myFile.txt");
```

Using json or csv is not out of the question either...

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = fileTextBlob.split('\n');
$(".myDiv").children("input").each(function(index, inputEl){
    var tmpStr = strings.shift();
    //Catch empty lines. Could add more logic to catch strings of all spaces, etc.
    while(!tmpStr && typeof(tmpStr) !== "undefined"){
        tmpStr = strings.shift();
    }
    $(inputEl).text(tmpStr);
})
```

Comment: This is close - can you explain the fileTextBlob part?

Comment: Sure. fileTextBlob represents the raw data from your text file. On a webpage, there are two primary ways you could get this data: allow the user to open a file (https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html), or, if your data is on your server, make an Ajax request to get the data:

var fileTextBlob;
$.get("myfile.txt", function(responseData){
    fileTextBlob = responseData;
    //Now that you have the data, you can update your page
    doUpdate();
})

In a perfect world, your server could send down JSON which you could parse instead (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the data as json array of objects

```
var data = [
  {
    "firstname": "Jon",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "age": 25
    },  {
      "firstname": "Jone",
      "lastname": "Doee",
      "age": 21
    }
  ]
```

Then with JQuery you could build the divs

```
var body = $('body');
$.each(data, function(index, value){
  body.append($('<input type="text" id="firstname' + index + '" >').text(value.firstname));
  body.append($('<input type="text" id="lastname' + index + '" >').text(value.lastname));
  body.append($('<input type="text" id="age' + index + '" >').text(value.age));
}
```

Edit - 
You can use getJSON to load the json file

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Comment: Thank you - this could work.  Its important that I call an external file still though.  Are you saying I build my txt file as a json file instead and use $('.myDiv').load ('myfile.json'); ?